# Spring Boot - Newly added column cause error

Tags: spring-boot, mysql-connector

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'confirm_token' in 'field list'
```

Newly added column to the database can not be seen while the exact same column name is existent both in the database & entity class.

I am using `SpringBoot mysqlconnector`. The column was added using flyway sql based migration.

I have tried renaming column but still the problem exists

code in the entity class  (Picked only one line)

```
@Column(name = "confirm_token")
private String confirmToken;
```

Any idea about where could be a problem?

Comment: Can you please post the generated SQL plus the StackTrace.

Comment: Try renaming `table` name(entity) instead of `column` name.

Comment: Can you post the create table statement and the entity? Even if the column exists it sound a different table, or look for case sensitive as well.

Comment: @SudhirOjha the error is gone after renaming the table. any explanation on how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the table name  (entity) to a new name, re-run the application and it solved the issue. and seems now it can work with original table name.